# Why is our Facebook page often out of date?

Tags: facebook

We have a page for our business on Facebook and often when I go there it is showing the page as if I've gone back in time. The feed is only showing old entries, the profile picture is from a few weeks ago, and even the photo albums don't show newer photos that we have added.

Sometimes it is up to a few weeks old.

But even when this happens, direct links to new stuff (e.g. photo albums) still work.

Often I can see different versions of the page just by using different browsers, or being logged in versus not, etc. But there doesn't seem to be any consistency to this.

The only thing I can think is that they are replicating their database and I'm seeing different versions.

I have searched high and low, but haven't come across any other mentions of this phenomenon. Have you seen it? Is it a known issue? Are there ways to get around it?

Answer (score 1):

This may be an issue with the temporary files for each browser. Depending on your browser, you need to go to your options and clear all browsing data (like cookies, cache, temporary files, and / or history - whatever your browser is calling all of the stuff).

Browsers save information from websites as temporary files on your computer so it will load faster the next time you visit because many of the files are already downloaded. These sometimes get old and need to be updated. And to update them, the easiest thing is to delete everything and visit again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't think this is the issue because today the page might be up to date and when I visit it tomorrow it might go back to what it looked like 2 weeks ago.